# Using Application.Evaluate for XNPV

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

I'm trying to use the XNPV function within VBA, however, the WorksheetFunction.XNPV doesn't  provide a parameter that corresponds to the rate.  I came across the Application.Evaluate workaround but I'm having trouble with the defined rate I'm using. My code gives me Error 2029 which I assume is due to the Evaluate function not recognizing the variable "low"

Here's my code for reference

```
Dim high            As Double       
Dim low             As Double       
Dim mid             As Double

low = 1
high = 100
mid = (low + high) / 2

Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=XNPV(low,CQ7:CQ367,E7:E367)")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reference a variable that you've created in the VBA code you have to concatenate it into the formula, you can't explicitly include it in a string as you've done above.

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=XNPV(low,CQ7:CQ367,E7:E367)")
```

should be

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=XNPV(" & low & ",CQ7:CQ367,E7:E367)")
```